# Label a function to be restricted

Tags: solidity, remix

Is it in Solidity possible to label a function, so that just the contact owner can call it? Or how could I do it?

I want to achieve something like this but in easy:

```
contract MyContract {
    address public owner;

    function MyContract() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function ownerOnly() public view returns(uint) {
        if(owner != msg.sender) throw;

        //return some private attributes which just the owner should see
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [modifiers](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html#restricting-access) are for.

```
modifier ownerOnly {
  if (msg.sender == owner) _;
}

function doSomething() ownerOnly {
  ...
}
```

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for...thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems to me the OP was asking about "private attributes that only the owner should see." A modifier doesn't do that. A modifier, at best, can disallow anyone from changing state, but anyone can see any data that's on chain (see below).

Comment: @ThomasJayRush you may be right. I just noticed his code comment after reading yours. OP - Can you confirm? (FYI - Downvote wasn’t from me)

Comment: It’s hard to tell because the first statement is about labeling a function so only the contract owner can call it. That’s different than attribute privacy (as you’ve pointed out). You should also point out in your answer about using a private blockchain.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, every transaction on the Ethereum chain is fully accessible to anyone with a node (or even access to EtherScan). The only way, currently, to protect your data is to either (a) don't put it on chain, to begin with, or (b) encrypt it prior to putting it on chain. I say "currently" because there are things like ZK-Snarks, that promise to solve this problem, but they are not fully available just yet.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The downvote is not from me. So everyone can see the attributes set in my contract, also the private ones?

Comment: There are no private ones.